# Alterar Tittle Section

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Boa noite, preciso de ajuda para que um texto acompanhe o título da página. Aqui deveria mostrar "teste" ao invés de "blog"
[image: Imagem de como está]

[image: Imagem de como está o código]

Comment: Poste o seu código, e não imagens. Desse jeito, fica difícil entender qual é o seu problema. O que posso te adiantar é que *talvez* o método [`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) pode ser seu amigo. Talvez.

Comment: Tem como alterar o título da página com uma função de JavaScript. Eu pesquisei e vi que utilizando `document.title = "Teste";` dá certo. Só não sei a função que usa para que, quando chegar em um lugar da página, ativar a função para alterar.